# duplicate variable text using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

(I rewrote this to make it clearer)

Can I use regex in Notepad++ to change this:

```
<audio>  
<source src="audio/words/word1.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>  
</audio>

<audio>  
<source src="audio/words/word2.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>  
</audio>
```

into this:

```
<audio>  
<source src="audio/words/word1.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>  
<source src="audio/words/word1.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>  
</audio>    

<audio>  
<source src="audio/words/word2.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>  
<source src="audio/words/word2.mp3" type='audio/mpeg'>  
</audio>
```

and so forth.

Solution found!! Thanks so much!

Comment: you need to define what "variable text" means. Until the first space occurs?

Comment: assuming it supports regex replacing, you can use a back-reference (`\1` or perhaps `$1`). e.g. `/(text-[a-z])/` -> `$1 $1`

Comment: Variable text just means that it can be any word or sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Search for `(text-.)` and replace with `$1 $1`. You can group sequences of text with parenthesis and you can access those groups using $1, $2, ... where the number is the index of the group from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(<source.*[\n|\r])$
```

replace

```
$1 $1
```

Update the answer with the user finding so everyone that google brings here can see the answer.

```
 (<source.*) >> \1 \1
```

Comment: I tried this in Notepad++ and Zeus, but can't make it work. Can you please give me some more info? I'm really new at this.

Comment: I got it: (<source.*) >> \1 \1

Thanks a lot!!